# How to pre-populate ngselect in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am grabbing some items through a `http` call and then want to pre-populate the `ngselect`, but using the `abstractcontrol.setvalue()` method does not seem to work.

**Template Code**

```
<ng-select [items]="cars"
         bindValue="code"
         bindLabel="displayName"
         formControlName="car"
         [clearable]="false"
         [searchable]="false"
         id="car"
         placeholder="Select a car">
```

**Component Code**

```
this.setValueForPrePopulatedPlanningDetail('car', car);

private setDefaultValue(fieldName: string, value: any) {
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
    const field = this.myFormGroup.get(fieldName);
    field.markAsDirty();
    field.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code detailing what you have tried so far. A small sample of your template and controller code would suffice in this case.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @richbai90 Updated with code

Comment: I don't know much about Angular > 1.x so I won't post this as an answer, but from what I can tell, you need to create a reference to your ng select that you can access in the component (IE this.ngSelect) and call the .select method on that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need set your result to the list (countries) and then use setvalue to choose the option

Set result to your list in your component:

```
this.countries = ['XPTO','XPTO2','XPTO3']
```

Define the following in your html:

```
<select>
   <option [value]="country" *ngFor="let country of countries">             {{country}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think question is about [_ng-select_](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select), not native _select_ element.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select), would be to assign the values to the `items` input binding.

For instance,

```
<ng-select [items]="cities2"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="id"
  [multiple]="true"
  placeholder="Select cities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCityIds">
</ng-select>
```

And on your component.ts, you will populate `ng-select` options by subscribing to the observable returned by the HTTP request, and assigning it the `cities2` property.

```
cities2: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getData.subscribe(res => {
    this.cities2 = res;
  });
}
```

This [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select) might not directly answer your queries, but it shows how the various input bindings (such as `items`) work with `ng-select`.

Comment: This doesn't show how to set a default selected value

Comment: What is the default value you want to set? You can set it using `ngModel`. Also, do you want to use to be able to select only 1? or multiple?